GitLab won't clone from repo in same project group
We have GitLab Community edition.
We have a bunch of projects in a group.  They are all deployed in the same way, so I want to use a shared pipeline definition.  I can achieve that by putting the pipeline definition into another project in the same group and using include:project to reference it from the .gitlab-ci.yml files.  So far, so good.
Now, my pipeline needs to run some PowerShell scripts for the deployment stages.  I have put them in the same project as the pipeline definition.  How can I access them?  I am trying to use git clone with the CI_JOB_TOKEN variable.  It appears to be making use of that token, but comes back with,
Cloning into 'my-deployment'...
remote: You are not allowed to download code from this project.
fatal: unable to access 'https://myserver/mygroup/my-deployment.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

What is going on?  I can include the .yml pipeline files in the same project but can't get at the other files?

I suspect this is an access right issue to the repository you're trying to clone. I ran into a similar issue some days ago, and it turned out that the project that was being attempted cloned had "Limit access to this project" enabled, and the project trying to clone the repository wasn't in the whitelist. This gave the same error as you're posting. You can find this setting in "Settings -> CI/CD -> Access Token" for the project.
This link to the GitLab documentation might also help you.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html#add-a-group-or-project-to-the-job-token-allowlist

Ok, yes.  It's Settings -> CICD -> Token Access (rather than "Access Token")
But in there I was able to turn off "Limit access to this project" and then it worked as desired.

What we actually ended up doing was

Create a new access token with read_repository rights to the desired repository.
Store the value of the access token in a variable available to the pipeline that needs to do the cloning.  Mask its value so it does not show up in logs.
Specify the variable value of the gitlab-ci-token predefined variable..  For example: https://gitlab-ci-token:$MYTOKENVAR@path/to/myrepo.git

The answer from @Alfie probably has the key to the explanation, but I think the implication is, I'd have to go through every project in the group setting the permissions, and remember to do it every time there was a new project added to the group, whereas a variable can be scoped to the entire group and inherited by every project automatically.
Update see my comment under @Alfie's answer: the CI_JOB_TOKEN was being limited to the one project.
